# SQLITE query GROUP BY with SUM Using Delphi and Zeos

Tags: sqlite, delphi, dll, zeos

I have an app created using Delphi XE3 accessing the SQLite database with Zeos Component.

A select command in SQLite that return 3 rows:

```
 select p.descricao, pg.valor
from pagamento pg
inner join venda v on pg.origem = 'venda' and v.id_venda = pg.id_origem
left join pagamento_tipo p on pg.id_pagamento_tipo = p.id_pagamento_tipo
where v.data >= '2021-01-19' and v.data <= '2021-01-19'
and v.ra_status_venda in ( 'Finalizado', 'Pedido')
```

[image]

but when I put the group command the information result is wrong.

```
    select p.descricao, sum(pg.valor) as valor
from pagamento pg
inner join venda v on pg.origem = 'venda' and v.id_venda = pg.id_origem
left join pagamento_tipo p on pg.id_pagamento_tipo = p.id_pagamento_tipo
where v.data >= '2021-01-19' and v.data <= '2021-01-19'
and v.ra_status_venda in ( 'Finalizado', 'Pedido')
group by descricao
```

[image]

the P02 not sum.

and, if I sum all row, without group by, the value was correct too.

```
select sum(pg.valor) as valor
from pagamento pg
inner join venda v on pg.origem = 'venda' and v.id_venda = pg.id_origem
left join pagamento_tipo p on pg.id_pagamento_tipo = p.id_pagamento_tipo
where v.data >= '2021-01-19' and v.data <= '2021-01-19'
and v.ra_status_venda in ( 'Finalizado', 'Pedido')
```

[image]

PS: in another period this commands sum correctly.
PS2 I'm using dll 32bits for windows.

Comment: It is wrong to use `,` as the decimal separator for numeric values. You should use `.`. In any case you should not get `0` as result, but `39`. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27

Comment: Tks for you response.The "," are used to show decimal separator in my country, but the value in database was correct as float. I'll try to put on fiddle.

Comment: The database field is NUMERIC type

Comment: With your first query, what does adding `typeof(pg.valor)` to the result columns give you?

Comment: typeof(pg.valor) return integer, integer, real.

Comment: Those look good. Yeah, set up a fiddle with sample data that reproduces this if you can; I don't see anything obvious especially given your edit.

Comment: Tks for you tips, I solve with your help. Forcing the valor field as Real. select  descricao, sum(cast(pg.valor as Real) ) as valor.

Comment: But, do you know why SQLite considers my field as an integer if on the table it is NUMERIC ?

Comment: That's what numeric affinity does. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity

Comment: It is not the column, but the value of that column that is considered as integer: https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof

Comment: I will change the type from NUMERIC to Real on tables to avoid this problem, if it works I'll post it here,

Answer (score 1):

With tips @Shawn and @forpas I solve this problem, the SQLite type of field NUMERIC converts the numbers to other types in the RUNTIME select command, how the two first values were INTEGER and the last value were Real, apparently my program not recognize two different types in the same column.

To solve I change the type of field in the database from NUMERIC to REAL.

Comment: SQLite does not convert numbers to other types unless you explicitly apply this conversion by code. Also SQLite sums integer and real values perfectly fine. The issue that you described in your question is not reproducible so we don't know the source of the problem.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=00f38dd7814bb69bc6b7c5388a717376

Comment: I'm using win 32 dll, and the result is different than fiddle. I updated the dll to the most recent version before open this question.

Comment: Anyway, how I can't check if the problem is the DLL, I edited the answer. tks

Comment: Also, using the fiddle you created, I changed to real type, and the typeof on all rows are the same (real) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a6201913b82a7ce91ed05e6166d3982

Comment: In my 1st comment under your question I said: *It is wrong to use , as the decimal separator for numeric values* and you replied: *the value in database was correct as float*. So, is it maybe that the problem is the app you use to fetch the results of your query? Execute the sql statements directly on your database by using a tool like DB Browser for SQLite, with the latest version of SQLite. If you get correct results then you know that the problem is your app. If the results are wrong (which I doubt) then the problem I suspect is with your data.

Comment: SQLite uses a dynamic type system, so the data type of the columns is not important here. You can get correct results even if the data type of the columns is TEXT: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a4574b4b0477eb09c3fd19f0a012329d

Comment: You are right,  I believe the problem really is my app. tks

Comment: I edited the question too, to explain the tools I'm using.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Delphi or Zeos, but it would help to post the app's code that returns these results, so maybe someone may have a solution for you.